# Magento 2.2.2 Products Not Showing Category and List Page

Tags: php, database, sql

I have a real hard time solving this issue.

The issue is products Not showing on front end Category Pages and Product Listing Pages after import via CSV -

Just shows We can't find products matching the selection.

However, if I go to the product in Admin and then RE-SAVE without Any changes  -  and clear cache that product

will show in front end - on product listing pages and category pages - and shows in Layered Navigation

One thing I noticed is that After resaving the product in Admin - it automatically is adding Color Black to the

product - even if I haven't selected it -

I then tested my import file by adding color Black to the products in the import file to check if they show on

front end  - but this did not fix the issue

In the database table, I also noticed for the resaved products and after it adds Black to the color_value column

and color column  49

I tried to match these settings for the products which were not resaved in admin but again these still did not

show on the front end

I imported over 30000 via CSV - all

1.are showing in Admin

2. are showing under the correct categories in Admin
3. Can be seen on the front end by going direct to the product page itself
4. Tested with making products in stock with qty 10  and out of stock with qty 0 -  both will not show in

product listing/category pages until they have been resaved in admin

5. Run reindex and cleared all caches

I have set Magento to Display out of Stock Products

The Qty for the products and is_in_stock   values are set correctly after import and also the products are

enabled

I have tried to export the products which I have resaved and show in product listing pages and then match each

attribute for the import -   however after import again the products NOT saved in Admin don't show on the front end

category and product listing pages.

Spent over 4 weeks on this and tried a lot of things and trial and error.

I checked the database table catalog_product_flat_1   and checked all attributes imported and compared the ones

showing on the front end and the ones which are not - and they made them identical however they still will not show

on front end unless the product has been resaved in the admin.

This is the same case when importing via another extension or application for Magento, for example, Firebear - this

the issue is happening whenever or whatever I use a CSV import.

Another issue is that if I resave the products and they then show on the front end - when I update those same

products via CSV import -  the values for example price and qty and is_in_stock   only change in admin and not

in front end - on product listing category pages -    I then have to resave again   and clear cache then the

updated changes are reflected on the front end

I am really stuck on

Comment: have your tried using command line ?php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: yes tried numerous times  and ran each index individually too. make sure

Comment: Delete the generated/metadata/global.php, and then clear cache php bin/magento c:c

Comment: i checked \generated\metadata\global.php and there is no global.php

Comment: are you importing from magento1 products, are you doing a migration?

Comment: i have tried importing with Improved Import & Export for Magento 2 extension by Firebear  also a desktop application called store manager for magento  Ir is import into new store / site not migration and not from magento 1 products

Comment: so you said that the product is showing on admin and not on frontend, go to product in admin and look at websites, do they show you the right website? they should be assigned to the website that you want it to show.

Comment: what do you have in your store_view_code column in your csv files?

Comment: store_view_code is blank But its also blank for the products which i resaved in admin and showing on front end - i exported all products to check -  also the products are being imported to Default product_websites  base

Comment: Just to clarify - not showing on front end means not showing on category landing pages / product listing pages  or accessed via layered navigation or site navigation but can be accesed if i enter url of product page direct in browser

Comment: if you have a local I believe your url rewrites are messed up, trucate url_rewrite and  catalog_url_rewrite_product_category completely and then run php bin/magento index:reindex, I repeat dont do on production do it on your local test environment

Comment: i dont have local

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problems with Products and Categories URLs. Every product need an URL to be displayed in Frontend.

Your product was imported without URL. When you re-save that product, Magento will auto generate a new URL and it will be showed.

**Conclusion**: you have to add/update records into `url_rewrite` table in order to make your products presented in Frontend.

Comment: i am running this extension for url rewrites   https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites   however it's taking a very long time - I have 30,000  sku and 1800 categories  at moment I am running for store 1 only     php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate 1       but very slow

Comment: can anyone recommend another method or extension which can do this taks faster?

Comment: @jt9489 I think you will need to read through all categories and products in order to generate the product URL and category-product URL. You should contact this guys: https://next-cart.com/supported-carts/magento/. They provide migration service for Magento 2 so I think they will have a solution for you. Magento 2 is so weird thing

Comment: the urls rewrite seems to have completed - however now even the products that were resaved previously and showing previously are no longer showing.

Comment: is there anyway to verify that this is a url rewrite issue or not?  as i said it completed url rewrite but the issue is still present

Comment: @jt9489 in the `url_rewrite` table, check the store_id, target_path. If both `request_path` and `target_path` work, you will need to re-index then clear cache.

Comment: Is it possible to compare using product id in phpmyadmin so after running in mysql it will output any differences between a product id which has been resaved and showing on front end and another which is not - to show exactly what settings and attributes and everything internal aswell

Comment: @jt9489 Yes. That's the way I used to check for errors. You should create a showed product and an error product, then compare the data of them. I have encountered your problem many times, typically the reason dues to Catalog Search Index and URL Rewrite. Make sure your Indexes working properly.

Comment: How can i make sure indexes are working properly? I check in admin and the show as being completed they take a very long time to finish - i run them from ssh commad reset first using php bin/magento indexer:reset   then run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: just to add when i resave product in admin it doesnt need reindex just clearing of cache and it shows on front end and search

Comment: @jt9489 Do you make sure your product has all necessary URLs in `url_rewrite` table? Because in order to be displayed in category page, it need a category-product URLs like this (target_path): `catalog/product/view/id/2/category/7`.

Comment: yes they are like thie catalog/product/view/id/1, catalog/product/view/id/1/category/2313, catalog/product/view/id/1/category/2 , catalog/product/view/id/1/category/2296  this is the product resaved and showing - the one that are not showing are same like this

Comment: What's the highest level of your categories? It may cause problem if the level's more than 4, you can find more information about this problem here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8018. Check out the `product_id` in this table: `catalog_category_product_index`. If everything's ok, check out these tables: `catalogsearch_*`.

Comment: we have magento 2.2.2 so checked vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Category/Action/Rows.php isRangingNeeded is returning false. other person on there had same issue it seems but no one replied after - i opened the tables you mentioned but what should i be looking for - they all seem to be populated

Comment: my category depth is 5 levels